# Is there a way to optimize this statement?

Tags: c, optimization

I have two `char`'s , `s1` and `s2` and have a statement

```
if ((s1 && !s2) || (!s1 && s2))
```

but I feel like that is redundant since the calculation involves looking at both `s1` and `!s1` separately, and the same for `s2` and `!s2`. For, by looking at `s1` and `s2`, you already have the information that underlies `!s1` and `!s2`. Is there a way to compress this statement?

Comment: Are `s1` and `s2` bools or ints?  If they are ints, are they any value or restricted to being 0 or 1?

Comment: They are `char`s being checked against `\0\` implicitly. I should've mentioned that. Sorry.

Comment: Unless you're doing this xor loads, what you've written is by far the most maintainable. Test the solutions as an inline function. seeing raw xor code as submitted would throw any developer

Comment: Why is this tagged as *bit-manipulation*? Those all are logical operators, and quite different from bit-wise operators.

Comment: If they are chars, don't attempt neither bit manipulation nor boolean logic on them. What is it that you are actually trying to do, check versus null termination?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That statement is a logical-exclusive-or for which there is no built-in operator. Under certain restrictions, you can convert it to a bitwise-exclusive-or `^`, but more generally it can be written as

```
if ( !s1 != !s2 )
```

The logical `not` operator `!` will convert a 0 to the logical `true` value, and will convert any other value to the logical `false` value. The results can then be tested with `!=`.

Comment: That works. Logical XOR can also be written like this `!!s1 ^ !!s2`

Comment: @BarmakShemirani: Or just `!s1 ^ !s2`.

Comment: Why not just s1^s2 ? Just for me to know...Doesn't it always work? What do you mean by "under certain restrictions"?

Comment: @A.M.D If one or both of the characters is 0, then `s1^s2` gives the correct result. And if `s1` and `s2` both have the same non-zero value, then `s1^s2` will be 0, which is correct. But if `s1` and `s2` are just random characters like `'A'` and `'B'` then `s1^s2` will give a non-zero result, which is wrong.

Answer (score 5):

I believe that the use of [conditional operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) `?:` operator would be easiest to read.

```
if (s1? !s2: s2) { 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If both are boolean:

```
if(s1 != s2)
```

Comment: It has been mentioned in the comments that they are `char`'s

Comment: Anything is boolean in C.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you are trying to do an XOR (exclusive OR). One or the other variable is true but not both or neither. In C languages this is done with

```
bool c = a^b
```

Comment: bool is not in every C,

Comment: Downvote because bitwise operators should not be used in logical context. Question mentioned that variables are of type `char`.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan It is in standard C. This is tagged C, so it is implicitly assumed to be about the current standard (ISO 9899:2011) and not about old, withdrawn standards.

Comment: @Lundin so you also means that I should not suggest "The C Programming book" by W. Kernighan, Dennis M. Ritchie to new students as it is withdrawn?

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan Indeed you should not. It is a bad book. Apart from it being outdated several times over, it is filled with errors and bad programming practice. Though of course if you call the "C bible" bad, you'll get hunted by religious fanatics.